# Looking for a WPF multicolumn list with scaling

Tags: wpf

I would like to create a multi-column list of checkboxes, but here's the catch - as I resize the window I would like everything to scale accordingly, including text size. I've been trying to make use of a WrapPanel and ViewBox but can't get the XAML right. Are these controls the best option or should I be using a ListBox (note I don't need selection functionality or scrollbars)? Any suggestions or examples on how I could achieve this would be much appreciated. I'm  using MVVM and the list will be data bound, if that makes a difference.

BTW since starting WPF I've been struggling to understand which controls size to their children and which size to their parent. Are there any good sites, cheat sheets, or whatever summarising the behaviour of each control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a variable number of child elements, you could put a [UniformGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid.aspx) into a ViewBox.

If the child elements have to be visualized by a DataTemplate, you would have to use an ItemsControl with the `ItemsPanel` property set to such a UniformGrid:

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Width="400" Height="200">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="4"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Background="AliceBlue">
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Label}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible to use a grid as the number of textblocks isn't fixed. They will also be databound, so I'll have to create the controls using a DataTemplate I guess.

Comment: Fantastic, many thanks. A well deserved green tick! How does it work? I don't understand how WPF knows to place each checkbox in a separate grid cell.

Comment: That's what the UniformGrid does. Each child in a seperate cell, then wrap around if the current column equals the `Columns` property (also works for `Rows`).